# Para poder utilizar o método tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices preciso de ter GPU no PC?

Tags: inteligência-artificial, aprendizagem-de-máquina, tensorflow, aprendizado-supervisionado

Estou a fazer o meu treino de tensorflow. Até aqui tudo bem:

```
data = numpy.random.random((1000, 32))
labels = numpy.random.random((1000, 10))
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Mas quando faço o treino com do seguinte modo dá erro:

```
data = numpy.random.random((1000, 32))
labels = numpy.random.random((1000, 10))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

Aparece o erro `StartAbort Out of range` em cada época:

```
Epoch 1/10
     32/Unknown - 1s 25ms/step - loss: 219.6890 - accuracy: 0.11002020-04-17 11:42:58.024503: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
32/32 [==============================] - 1s 25ms/step - loss: 219.6890 - accuracy: 0.1100
```

Ajudem-me, por favor! Sou novo no tensorflow e também aqui, não sejam muito rigorosos comigo.

Comment: A resposta ao título é não, o erro do corpo que é um problema diferente pode ser aprendido em na resposta já dada e likada acima.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero, mas ainda vou continuar a procurar porque eu não criei qualquer coisa manualmente. Apenas estou a utilizar os métodos já criados seguindo o tutorial oficial em https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/overview?hl=pt_br

Comment: Recomendo usar keras diretamente https://keras.io/

Comment: Obrigado @AnnaMaule. Vou tentar essa abordagem.